# Rename column in a partitioned table

Tags: oracle, partitioning, oracle-11g, alter-table

I want to rename a column in a partitioned table.
Will oracle do this for all partitions?
Is there anything special for this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming a column is a simple dictionary update. Yes, it will be done for all partitions.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t1 (
       c1   NUMBER,
       c2   VARCHAR2(30),
       c3   NUMBER,
       c4   NUMBER, constraint t1_pk primary key (c1, c4) using index local)
  PARTITION BY LIST (c4) (
       PARTITION p10 VALUES (10),
       PARTITION p20 VALUES (20),
       PARTITION p30 VALUES (30,40));

Table created.

SQL> alter table t1 rename column c2 to c5;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t1 rename column c4 to c6;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t1 rename column c1 to c7;

Table altered.

SQL> desc t1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 C7                                        NOT NULL NUMBER
 C5                                                 VARCHAR2(30)
 C3                                                 NUMBER
 C6                                        NOT NULL NUMBER
```